# How can I build standalone static library in c for a firmware module

Tags: c, gcc, static-libraries, firmware

How can I build a standalone static library (.a) for a firmware module and link that static library in the main project (without providing access to header files in that module) ?

I know about ar command but that is just compiling the .c files, when I try to use the functions in one of the .c files of the firmware module it shows me implicit function deceleration warning. I do not want to export the .h files but rather just provide a libexample.a package to the developer to use the firmware module.

Will the pre-compiled header work in this scenario?

Comment: If you want to compile code that uses a library function in C, you need the header files. The `.a` is insufficient.

Comment: The code compiling against the library needs to know about the global variables and functions that it is going to be linking against.  If you don't want to include a header, then all of those things will have to be defined in the source of the code itself.  May as well provide the header, though; much more convenient.

Comment: in both cases 'static library' or `archive` and in `shared library` or `shared object`, you need to include in your calling application, you need to include the header file that contain the library `API`! I guess you are familiar with all the diferences betwen `so` and `static library`